# MVC Get DropDownListFor Selected value via model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have created one module called City master.

there are two fields one **Text** for city name and one **DropDownlist** to select Sate.

i am getting error
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
while i try to update state value

here is my **Model**

```
        public int AID { get; set; }      
        public string CITYNAME { get; set; }  
        public int STATEAID { get; set; } 
        public List<STATEMST1> StateDropDownList { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CITYNAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.STATEAID, new SelectList(Model.StateDropDownList, "AID", "STATENAME"),"--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })


 <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CITYMST1 cITYMST1)
        {
            try
            {
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBSCTEST"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
                    (@" UPDATE CITYMST (CITYNAME = @CITYNAME,STATEAID = @STATEAID,MODUSERAID = (SELECT AID FROM USERSMST WHERE EMPID = @EMPID),
                    MODDATE = GETDATE())", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITYNAME", cITYMST1.CITYNAME);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATEAID", cITYMST1.STATEAID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", HttpContext.Session["id"]);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    con.Close();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

i tried this
http://termifaker.blogspot.com/2017/09/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue.html

but i cant understan why i am receiving null NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your model to the view  `return View(yourModel);`

Juste an other this you have a naming problem with all those capital letters. there is some convention for properties naming.

Answer (score 0):

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CITYMST1 cITYMST1)
        {
            try
            {
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBSCTEST"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
                    (@" UPDATE CITYMST (CITYNAME = @CITYNAME,STATEAID = @STATEAID,MODUSERAID = (SELECT AID FROM USERSMST WHERE EMPID = @EMPID),
                    MODDATE = GETDATE())", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITYNAME", cITYMST1.CITYNAME);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATEAID", cITYMST1.STATEAID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", HttpContext.Session["id"]);
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    con.Close();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                cITYMST1.StateDropDownList = //TODO: load your states again here
                return View(cITYMST1);
            }
        }
```